# if false, do nothing in tickscript

Tags: if-statement, influxdb, influxql, kapacitor

In tickscript the norwal way to do if else is in the following:

> if(condition, true expression, false expression)

However, for the false expression, I want my code to do nothing as in the following:

> if(condition, true print("that is true"), false -do nothing-  )

I already tried putting some blank and/or deleting false expression part but it did not work.
Is there a way to do that in tickscript?